# Maven option is not found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-indigo

I am in Eclipse Indigo and I have installed m2eclipse plugin. I saw in Eclipse Helios there is an option Maven in the right click menu, when I clicked on a Project, but this option is not present now.

I have installed Maven from both of the marketplace and also from adding site in Install new software option in Eclipse(Help->Install New Software).

What I am doing wrong.

This question was asked before in SO, but I tried the solution provided there.

Is this option is really not present? What I want is to enable Maven Dependency Management of a Dynamic Web Project of Eclipse.

Comment: Could you give some details? Which distro (Java, JEE, ...)? On which question on SO do you reference? Please list the steps you are doing, and what your expectation there is.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to do a right click on the project, then choose `Configure` → `Convert to Maven project`

Answer (score 6):

Right Click on the Project --> Configure --> Convert to Maven Project.

It will show Maven Related Options.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to import the project as Maven project.

Comment: I always prefer to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to install in Eclipse older versions, use **YOXOS Marketplace - by EclipseSource**. Search for "Maven" in marketplace. You will get **Maven Integration for Eclipse** provided by Sonatype. Use that to install.

Answer (score 2):

After installing m2eclipse plugin, go to Window -> Preferences. Check "Maven" is enlisted at the left panel list

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me because I imported a parent folder as a project.  so all my projects where sub directories of this parent folder and not a project them selves.  after deleting them (only) from the workspace and re importing them as separate projects, maven worked fine.